# How do I run an external healthcheck command in Amazon ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

Is it possible to change the HealthStatus of an ECS Task from another container or service, ideally using the AWS API (e.g. boto3)?

I'm working around the limitation that Docker `HEALTHCHECK` and AWS task `healthCheck` definitions are commands that must run inside the container being checked. In my case, the task is running untrusted code, so it is preferable not to install toys like `curl` within the container itself. I already have another service which is tending these tasks, and it'd be convenient if this service could change their health status as soon as it knows there's a problem.

**How do I set the `healthStatus` of a task from outside the container?** I'm ~75% sure I saw a description of this somewhere, but now I can't reproduce the Google search terms that led to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I'd run across before; it was in the context of [autoscaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/healthcheck.html).

It looks like I can't set the health status on a *task*, but I can set the health status of an *instance*. This is unfortunately not what I want; multiple tasks will be running on a single instance and many of them will be healthy as one fails.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to set an "external" health check for a container. In the end I'm resorting to calling `ecs.stop_task(...)` from the another service.